# Issue with firewalld and ebtables

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, centos7

I am just setting up a server that occupies firewalld as the main firewall, but I have a problem ... doing

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

it appears that the service is running, but with certain problems

```
Feb 06 03:17:53 VPS1256 systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: WARNING: Failed to load nf_conntrack module: modprobe: ERROR: could not find module by name='nf_conntrack'
                                         modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Function not implemented
                                         modprobe: ERROR: Error running install command for nf_conntrack
                                         modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Operation not permitted
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: ERROR: Failed to read file "/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'
Feb 06 03:17:54 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: WARNING: Failed to get and parse nf_conntrack_helper setting
Feb 06 03:17:55 VPS1256 firewalld[1667]: WARNING: ebtables not usable, disabling ethernet bridge firewall.
```

What are these errors due to? Any way to fix them?

Comment: Linux VPS1256 2.6.32-042stab145.3 #1 SMP Thu Jun 11 14:05:04 MSK 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You will need to contact your VPS provider or switch to another VPS. See the linked question above for details.